# Git Flow should the release to production be done from release branch or Main/trunk branch

Tags: git, git-flow

We use Git Flow when deploying to production environment do we deploy from release branch or main/trunk branch.

The reason for asking is if we merge to trunk and deploy to production how do we ensure that the merge is done properly. It looks like merges code is deployed to production without testing is this correct? How do we ensure what has been merged to Main branch is correct?

Comment: It is up to you.  We currently deploy from release, but it doesn't have to be that way.

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated in [Release Branch](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow#related-post-sidebar-flyout), if there have not been any modification on the master branch (and it should have been no new commit), the merge (from release to master) should be a trivial one:

[image: release]

But you should still run your tests from that 1.0 release commit before the actual deployment.